# Excel to to remove duplicate based on average

Tags: excel

I have an excel table with only duplicated IDs (in first column) and corresponding **values** in the subsequent columns. I calculated the average of all **values** and inserted as second column. Now I would like to retain only the rows with highest averaged item from the duplicated keys.

For example,

```
ID   AVG   Value1   Value2   Value 3
01   13.6     3       15       23
01   26       22      43       13
02   14.6     8       15       21
```

Results,

```
ID   AVG   Value1   Value2   Value 3    
01   26       22      43       13
02   14.6     8       15       21
```

How can it be done in EXCEL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retain the duplicates with the highest value in the AVG column, sort the data by ID, then by AVG.

Then use the "Remove Duplicates" command on the Data ribbon and select the ID column only.

Data sorted by ID and AVG:

[image]

Apply "Remove Duplicates" with ribbon command and select ID column only

[image]

The result is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would color-mark all the duplicate values in the ID column, using Conditional Formatting (Highlight Cells Rules > Duplicate Values) and then sort the table by:
1. ID column - by color
2. Average column - in descending order
Then you can just delete the bottom lines, which contain the lower duplicate values.

Comment: Thank you @teylyn for the nice explanation. It worked. Also thanks GalAbra for the alterrnative method..